# Python - w1o2 - Problem with number conversion base exaples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

__version__ = '1.1'
__authorname__ = 'Anonymous'
__author__ = 'anonymous'
__studentnummer__ = '000000000'
__opgave__ = 'w1o2.py'

import sys
import getopt

from w1o2_tbl import kAddTbl


def myAdd(a, b, base=10):
    aLen = len(a)
    bLen = len(b)
    n = max(aLen, bLen)
    r, c = "", '0'
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        ai = a[-i] if i <= aLen else '0'
        bi = b[-i] if i <= bLen else '0'
        c1, s1 = kAddTbl[base][c, ai]
        c2, s2 = kAddTbl[base][s1, bi]
        c = c1 if c1 != '0' else c2
        r = s2 + r
    if c == '1': r = c + r
    return r


gVbs = False
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tests = [
        ("9", "12", "21", 10),
        ("64", "7", "71", 10),
        ("923", "98", "1021", 10),
    ]
    for a, b, r, base in tests:
        c = myAdd(a, b, base)
        if c != r:
            print('Error: B{}:\t{} + {} != {} [{}]'.format(base, a, b, c, r))
        else:
            print('B{}:\t{}+{}={}'.format(base, a, b, c))
    print('Tests done.')
    print('Dit programma is gemaakt door: ' + __authorname__ + " " + __studentnummer__)
```

But it does only print the right answers of base 10 from this table:

```
# Generated by w1o2_gen.py
kAddTbl={
   2: {
     ('0', '0'): ('0', '0'), ('0', '1'): ('0', '1'),
     ('1', '0'): ('0', '1'), ('1', '1'): ('1', '0'),
  },
   4: {
     ('0', '0'): ('0', '0'), ('0', '1'): ('0', '1'), ('0', '2'): ('0', '2'), ('0', '3'): ('0', '3'),
     ('1', '0'): ('0', '1'), ('1', '1'): ('0', '2'), ('1', '2'): ('0', '3'), ('1', '3'): ('1', '0'),
     ('2', '0'): ('0', '2'), ('2', '1'): ('0', '3'), ('2', '2'): ('1', '0'), ('2', '3'): ('1', '1'),
     ('3', '0'): ('0', '3'), ('3', '1'): ('1', '0'), ('3', '2'): ('1', '1'), ('3', '3'): ('1', '2'),
  },
   8: {
     ('0', '0'): ('0', '0'), ('0', '1'): ('0', '1'), ('0', '2'): ('0', '2'), ('0', '3'): ('0', '3'),
     ('0', '4'): ('0', '4'), ('0', '5'): ('0', '5'), ('0', '6'): ('0', '6'), ('0', '7'): ('0', '7'),
     ('1', '0'): ('0', '1'), ('1', '1'): ('0', '2'), ('1', '2'): ('0', '3'), ('1', '3'): ('0', '4'),
     ('1', '4'): ('0', '5'), ('1', '5'): ('0', '6'), ('1', '6'): ('0', '7'), ('1', '7'): ('1', '0'),
     ('2', '0'): ('0', '2'), ('2', '1'): ('0', '3'), ('2', '2'): ('0', '4'), ('2', '3'): ('0', '5'),
     ('2', '4'): ('0', '6'), ('2', '5'): ('0', '7'), ('2', '6'): ('1', '0'), ('2', '7'): ('1', '1'),
     ('3', '0'): ('0', '3'), ('3', '1'): ('0', '4'), ('3', '2'): ('0', '5'), ('3', '3'): ('0', '6'),
     ('3', '4'): ('0', '7'), ('3', '5'): ('1', '0'), ('3', '6'): ('1', '1'), ('3', '7'): ('1', '2'),
     ('4', '0'): ('0', '4'), ('4', '1'): ('0', '5'), ('4', '2'): ('0', '6'), ('4', '3'): ('0', '7'),
     ('4', '4'): ('1', '0'), ('4', '5'): ('1', '1'), ('4', '6'): ('1', '2'), ('4', '7'): ('1', '3'),
     ('5', '0'): ('0', '5'), ('5', '1'): ('0', '6'), ('5', '2'): ('0', '7'), ('5', '3'): ('1', '0'),
     ('5', '4'): ('1', '1'), ('5', '5'): ('1', '2'), ('5', '6'): ('1', '3'), ('5', '7'): ('1', '4'),
     ('6', '0'): ('0', '6'), ('6', '1'): ('0', '7'), ('6', '2'): ('1', '0'), ('6', '3'): ('1', '1'),
     ('6', '4'): ('1', '2'), ('6', '5'): ('1', '3'), ('6', '6'): ('1', '4'), ('6', '7'): ('1', '5'),
     ('7', '0'): ('0', '7'), ('7', '1'): ('1', '0'), ('7', '2'): ('1', '1'), ('7', '3'): ('1', '2'),
     ('7', '4'): ('1', '3'), ('7', '5'): ('1', '4'), ('7', '6'): ('1', '5'), ('7', '7'): ('1', '6'),
  },
  10: {
     ('0', '0'): ('0', '0'), ('0', '1'): ('0', '1'), ('0', '2'): ('0', '2'), ('0', '3'): ('0', '3'), ('0', '4'): ('0', '4'),
     ('0', '5'): ('0', '5'), ('0', '6'): ('0', '6'), ('0', '7'): ('0', '7'), ('0', '8'): ('0', '8'), ('0', '9'): ('0', '9'),
     ('1', '0'): ('0', '1'), ('1', '1'): ('0', '2'), ('1', '2'): ('0', '3'), ('1', '3'): ('0', '4'), ('1', '4'): ('0', '5'),
     ('1', '5'): ('0', '6'), ('1', '6'): ('0', '7'), ('1', '7'): ('0', '8'), ('1', '8'): ('0', '9'), ('1', '9'): ('1', '0'),
     ('2', '0'): ('0', '2'), ('2', '1'): ('0', '3'), ('2', '2'): ('0', '4'), ('2', '3'): ('0', '5'), ('2', '4'): ('0', '6'),
     ('2', '5'): ('0', '7'), ('2', '6'): ('0', '8'), ('2', '7'): ('0', '9'), ('2', '8'): ('1', '0'), ('2', '9'): ('1', '1'),
     ('3', '0'): ('0', '3'), ('3', '1'): ('0', '4'), ('3', '2'): ('0', '5'), ('3', '3'): ('0', '6'), ('3', '4'): ('0', '7'),
     ('3', '5'): ('0', '8'), ('3', '6'): ('0', '9'), ('3', '7'): ('1', '0'), ('3', '8'): ('1', '1'), ('3', '9'): ('1', '2'),
     ('4', '0'): ('0', '4'), ('4', '1'): ('0', '5'), ('4', '2'): ('0', '6'), ('4', '3'): ('0', '7'), ('4', '4'): ('0', '8'),
     ('4', '5'): ('0', '9'), ('4', '6'): ('1', '0'), ('4', '7'): ('1', '1'), ('4', '8'): ('1', '2'), ('4', '9'): ('1', '3'),
     ('5', '0'): ('0', '5'), ('5', '1'): ('0', '6'), ('5', '2'): ('0', '7'), ('5', '3'): ('0', '8'), ('5', '4'): ('0', '9'),
     ('5', '5'): ('1', '0'), ('5', '6'): ('1', '1'), ('5', '7'): ('1', '2'), ('5', '8'): ('1', '3'), ('5', '9'): ('1', '4'),
     ('6', '0'): ('0', '6'), ('6', '1'): ('0', '7'), ('6', '2'): ('0', '8'), ('6', '3'): ('0', '9'), ('6', '4'): ('1', '0'),
     ('6', '5'): ('1', '1'), ('6', '6'): ('1', '2'), ('6', '7'): ('1', '3'), ('6', '8'): ('1', '4'), ('6', '9'): ('1', '5'),
     ('7', '0'): ('0', '7'), ('7', '1'): ('0', '8'), ('7', '2'): ('0', '9'), ('7', '3'): ('1', '0'), ('7', '4'): ('1', '1'),
     ('7', '5'): ('1', '2'), ('7', '6'): ('1', '3'), ('7', '7'): ('1', '4'), ('7', '8'): ('1', '5'), ('7', '9'): ('1', '6'),
     ('8', '0'): ('0', '8'), ('8', '1'): ('0', '9'), ('8', '2'): ('1', '0'), ('8', '3'): ('1', '1'), ('8', '4'): ('1', '2'),
     ('8', '5'): ('1', '3'), ('8', '6'): ('1', '4'), ('8', '7'): ('1', '5'), ('8', '8'): ('1', '6'), ('8', '9'): ('1', '7'),
     ('9', '0'): ('0', '9'), ('9', '1'): ('1', '0'), ('9', '2'): ('1', '1'), ('9', '3'): ('1', '2'), ('9', '4'): ('1', '3'),
     ('9', '5'): ('1', '4'), ('9', '6'): ('1', '5'), ('9', '7'): ('1', '6'), ('9', '8'): ('1', '7'), ('9', '9'): ('1', '8'),
  },
  16: {
     ('0', '0'): ('0', '0'), ('0', '1'): ('0', '1'), ('0', '2'): ('0', '2'), ('0', '3'): ('0', '3'),
     ('0', '4'): ('0', '4'), ('0', '5'): ('0', '5'), ('0', '6'): ('0', '6'), ('0', '7'): ('0', '7'),
     ('0', '8'): ('0', '8'), ('0', '9'): ('0', '9'), ('0', 'A'): ('0', 'A'), ('0', 'B'): ('0', 'B'),
     ('0', 'C'): ('0', 'C'), ('0', 'D'): ('0', 'D'), ('0', 'E'): ('0', 'E'), ('0', 'F'): ('0', 'F'),
     ('1', '0'): ('0', '1'), ('1', '1'): ('0', '2'), ('1', '2'): ('0', '3'), ('1', '3'): ('0', '4'),
     ('1', '4'): ('0', '5'), ('1', '5'): ('0', '6'), ('1', '6'): ('0', '7'), ('1', '7'): ('0', '8'),
     ('1', '8'): ('0', '9'), ('1', '9'): ('0', 'A'), ('1', 'A'): ('0', 'B'), ('1', 'B'): ('0', 'C'),
     ('1', 'C'): ('0', 'D'), ('1', 'D'): ('0', 'E'), ('1', 'E'): ('0', 'F'), ('1', 'F'): ('1', '0'),
     ('2', '0'): ('0', '2'), ('2', '1'): ('0', '3'), ('2', '2'): ('0', '4'), ('2', '3'): ('0', '5'),
     ('2', '4'): ('0', '6'), ('2', '5'): ('0', '7'), ('2', '6'): ('0', '8'), ('2', '7'): ('0', '9'),
     ('2', '8'): ('0', 'A'), ('2', '9'): ('0', 'B'), ('2', 'A'): ('0', 'C'), ('2', 'B'): ('0', 'D'),
     ('2', 'C'): ('0', 'E'), ('2', 'D'): ('0', 'F'), ('2', 'E'): ('1', '0'), ('2', 'F'): ('1', '1'),
     ('3', '0'): ('0', '3'), ('3', '1'): ('0', '4'), ('3', '2'): ('0', '5'), ('3', '3'): ('0', '6'),
     ('3', '4'): ('0', '7'), ('3', '5'): ('0', '8'), ('3', '6'): ('0', '9'), ('3', '7'): ('0', 'A'),
     ('3', '8'): ('0', 'B'), ('3', '9'): ('0', 'C'), ('3', 'A'): ('0', 'D'), ('3', 'B'): ('0', 'E'),
     ('3', 'C'): ('0', 'F'), ('3', 'D'): ('1', '0'), ('3', 'E'): ('1', '1'), ('3', 'F'): ('1', '2'),
     ('4', '0'): ('0', '4'), ('4', '1'): ('0', '5'), ('4', '2'): ('0', '6'), ('4', '3'): ('0', '7'),
     ('4', '4'): ('0', '8'), ('4', '5'): ('0', '9'), ('4', '6'): ('0', 'A'), ('4', '7'): ('0', 'B'),
     ('4', '8'): ('0', 'C'), ('4', '9'): ('0', 'D'), ('4', 'A'): ('0', 'E'), ('4', 'B'): ('0', 'F'),
     ('4', 'C'): ('1', '0'), ('4', 'D'): ('1', '1'), ('4', 'E'): ('1', '2'), ('4', 'F'): ('1', '3'),
     ('5', '0'): ('0', '5'), ('5', '1'): ('0', '6'), ('5', '2'): ('0', '7'), ('5', '3'): ('0', '8'),
     ('5', '4'): ('0', '9'), ('5', '5'): ('0', 'A'), ('5', '6'): ('0', 'B'), ('5', '7'): ('0', 'C'),
     ('5', '8'): ('0', 'D'), ('5', '9'): ('0', 'E'), ('5', 'A'): ('0', 'F'), ('5', 'B'): ('1', '0'),
     ('5', 'C'): ('1', '1'), ('5', 'D'): ('1', '2'), ('5', 'E'): ('1', '3'), ('5', 'F'): ('1', '4'),
     ('6', '0'): ('0', '6'), ('6', '1'): ('0', '7'), ('6', '2'): ('0', '8'), ('6', '3'): ('0', '9'),
     ('6', '4'): ('0', 'A'), ('6', '5'): ('0', 'B'), ('6', '6'): ('0', 'C'), ('6', '7'): ('0', 'D'),
     ('6', '8'): ('0', 'E'), ('6', '9'): ('0', 'F'), ('6', 'A'): ('1', '0'), ('6', 'B'): ('1', '1'),
     ('6', 'C'): ('1', '2'), ('6', 'D'): ('1', '3'), ('6', 'E'): ('1', '4'), ('6', 'F'): ('1', '5'),
     ('7', '0'): ('0', '7'), ('7', '1'): ('0', '8'), ('7', '2'): ('0', '9'), ('7', '3'): ('0', 'A'),
     ('7', '4'): ('0', 'B'), ('7', '5'): ('0', 'C'), ('7', '6'): ('0', 'D'), ('7', '7'): ('0', 'E'),
     ('7', '8'): ('0', 'F'), ('7', '9'): ('1', '0'), ('7', 'A'): ('1', '1'), ('7', 'B'): ('1', '2'),
     ('7', 'C'): ('1', '3'), ('7', 'D'): ('1', '4'), ('7', 'E'): ('1', '5'), ('7', 'F'): ('1', '6'),
     ('8', '0'): ('0', '8'), ('8', '1'): ('0', '9'), ('8', '2'): ('0', 'A'), ('8', '3'): ('0', 'B'),
     ('8', '4'): ('0', 'C'), ('8', '5'): ('0', 'D'), ('8', '6'): ('0', 'E'), ('8', '7'): ('0', 'F'),
     ('8', '8'): ('1', '0'), ('8', '9'): ('1', '1'), ('8', 'A'): ('1', '2'), ('8', 'B'): ('1', '3'),
     ('8', 'C'): ('1', '4'), ('8', 'D'): ('1', '5'), ('8', 'E'): ('1', '6'), ('8', 'F'): ('1', '7'),
     ('9', '0'): ('0', '9'), ('9', '1'): ('0', 'A'), ('9', '2'): ('0', 'B'), ('9', '3'): ('0', 'C'),
     ('9', '4'): ('0', 'D'), ('9', '5'): ('0', 'E'), ('9', '6'): ('0', 'F'), ('9', '7'): ('1', '0'),
     ('9', '8'): ('1', '1'), ('9', '9'): ('1', '2'), ('9', 'A'): ('1', '3'), ('9', 'B'): ('1', '4'),
     ('9', 'C'): ('1', '5'), ('9', 'D'): ('1', '6'), ('9', 'E'): ('1', '7'), ('9', 'F'): ('1', '8'),
     ('A', '0'): ('0', 'A'), ('A', '1'): ('0', 'B'), ('A', '2'): ('0', 'C'), ('A', '3'): ('0', 'D'),
     ('A', '4'): ('0', 'E'), ('A', '5'): ('0', 'F'), ('A', '6'): ('1', '0'), ('A', '7'): ('1', '1'),
     ('A', '8'): ('1', '2'), ('A', '9'): ('1', '3'), ('A', 'A'): ('1', '4'), ('A', 'B'): ('1', '5'),
     ('A', 'C'): ('1', '6'), ('A', 'D'): ('1', '7'), ('A', 'E'): ('1', '8'), ('A', 'F'): ('1', '9'),
     ('B', '0'): ('0', 'B'), ('B', '1'): ('0', 'C'), ('B', '2'): ('0', 'D'), ('B', '3'): ('0', 'E'),
     ('B', '4'): ('0', 'F'), ('B', '5'): ('1', '0'), ('B', '6'): ('1', '1'), ('B', '7'): ('1', '2'),
     ('B', '8'): ('1', '3'), ('B', '9'): ('1', '4'), ('B', 'A'): ('1', '5'), ('B', 'B'): ('1', '6'),
     ('B', 'C'): ('1', '7'), ('B', 'D'): ('1', '8'), ('B', 'E'): ('1', '9'), ('B', 'F'): ('1', 'A'),
     ('C', '0'): ('0', 'C'), ('C', '1'): ('0', 'D'), ('C', '2'): ('0', 'E'), ('C', '3'): ('0', 'F'),
     ('C', '4'): ('1', '0'), ('C', '5'): ('1', '1'), ('C', '6'): ('1', '2'), ('C', '7'): ('1', '3'),
     ('C', '8'): ('1', '4'), ('C', '9'): ('1', '5'), ('C', 'A'): ('1', '6'), ('C', 'B'): ('1', '7'),
     ('C', 'C'): ('1', '8'), ('C', 'D'): ('1', '9'), ('C', 'E'): ('1', 'A'), ('C', 'F'): ('1', 'B'),
     ('D', '0'): ('0', 'D'), ('D', '1'): ('0', 'E'), ('D', '2'): ('0', 'F'), ('D', '3'): ('1', '0'),
     ('D', '4'): ('1', '1'), ('D', '5'): ('1', '2'), ('D', '6'): ('1', '3'), ('D', '7'): ('1', '4'),
     ('D', '8'): ('1', '5'), ('D', '9'): ('1', '6'), ('D', 'A'): ('1', '7'), ('D', 'B'): ('1', '8'),
     ('D', 'C'): ('1', '9'), ('D', 'D'): ('1', 'A'), ('D', 'E'): ('1', 'B'), ('D', 'F'): ('1', 'C'),
     ('E', '0'): ('0', 'E'), ('E', '1'): ('0', 'F'), ('E', '2'): ('1', '0'), ('E', '3'): ('1', '1'),
     ('E', '4'): ('1', '2'), ('E', '5'): ('1', '3'), ('E', '6'): ('1', '4'), ('E', '7'): ('1', '5'),
     ('E', '8'): ('1', '6'), ('E', '9'): ('1', '7'), ('E', 'A'): ('1', '8'), ('E', 'B'): ('1', '9'),
     ('E', 'C'): ('1', 'A'), ('E', 'D'): ('1', 'B'), ('E', 'E'): ('1', 'C'), ('E', 'F'): ('1', 'D'),
     ('F', '0'): ('0', 'F'), ('F', '1'): ('1', '0'), ('F', '2'): ('1', '1'), ('F', '3'): ('1', '2'),
     ('F', '4'): ('1', '3'), ('F', '5'): ('1', '4'), ('F', '6'): ('1', '5'), ('F', '7'): ('1', '6'),
     ('F', '8'): ('1', '7'), ('F', '9'): ('1', '8'), ('F', 'A'): ('1', '9'), ('F', 'B'): ('1', 'A'),
     ('F', 'C'): ('1', 'B'), ('F', 'D'): ('1', 'C'), ('F', 'E'): ('1', 'D'), ('F', 'F'): ('1', 'E'),
  },
}
```

And this is what they want:

Implement an add function myAdd, this function has two string arguments that are a number in one represent a certain base (base). The intention is that with the help of an addition table kAddTbl the
add addition. If you add two digits (characters) you get the sum (s) and the carry (c). This one
addition you must perform smart for all digits in the two strings. Note if the base is 16 there are also
letters (A .. F).

Now the problem is that base 10 works fine although is does not give any error. But if I change the Base to something different existing in the table it gives an error.

Can somebody help me with it?

Comment: Can you show us the error?

Comment: line 39, in <module>
    c = myAdd(a, b, base) and line 23, in myAdd
    c1, s1 = kAddTbl[base][c, ai]
KeyError: ('0', '9')
when I change the the base to 4 and also at the testcode from the 10 to a 4.

Comment: And what are the parameters being passed into the function that produce that error?

Comment: def myAdd(a, b, base=10): is changed to base=4
and         ("9", "12", "21", 10),
        ("64", "7", "71", 10),
        ("923", "98", "1021", 10), now has all 4's on the end to test base 4.

Comment: In base 4, the digits "6", "7", "8", and "9" are not used. An error would be the correct behaviour in that scenario, because you're asking your function to do a nonsensical thing.

Comment: Then the code is perfectly fine I think. Thank you for your input :D